# loading images and data from mysql into Flash using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I have a mysql database where the name of the products and prices and details get saved on there. This is done using PHP. and it works fine.

I just need to load the images of the products and their details into flash using AS3.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "../config/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 6");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="17%" valign="top"><a href="../product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="../inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            $' . $price . '<br />
            <a href="../product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
<?php echo $dynamicList; ?>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can create a XML or JSON structure using PHP and call the service from a flash/flex app. 

Here you can find the code to generate the XML:
http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/crear-un-archivo-xml-con-un-resultado-de-mysql-en-php-c68404l/

Comment: And here you can find the example to read the XML using Flash:
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/

Comment: Thanks but the first link you gave me is not English!! i dont understand it

Comment: I think the answer can be useful to you =)

Answer (score 0):

1.- Use PHP and SQL to generate a XML file

-> http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576499-converting-mysql-queries-to-xml/

2.- use Flash/Flex to display the data than you obtained from your XML

-> http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/

3.- Use your imagination and generate some great stuff:

-> http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3slideshow/